# Unable to disable dynamic IPv6 address

Tags: networking, kernel, ipv6, dynamic-ip

I have a bridge interface named `vms` with one IPv4 and one IPv6 address statically assigned via `netplan`. I have configured `radvd` to send router advertisements on this interface to assign dynamic IPv6 addresses to virtual machines connected to that bridge. I have configured the following kernel parameters that should disable dynamic addresses on the bridge itself:

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/vms # for f in accept_ra accept_ra_pinfo autoconf forwarding; do echo "$f = $(cat $f)"; done
accept_ra = 0
accept_ra_pinfo = 0
autoconf = 0
forwarding = 1
```

Nevertheless, the interface `vms` gets a dynamic IPv6 address as soon as `radvd` runs:

```
# \ip a s dev vms
3: vms: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:aa:00:bb:cc:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 x:x:x:x:fcaa:ff:febb:ccdd/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 86291sec preferred_lft 14291sec
    inet6 x:x:x:x::/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::fcaa:ff:febb:ccdd/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

What gives?

EDIT: Running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.